# jQuery submit form on linkClick event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Form

`@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id="form"}))
{ //fields}`


Link

```
<div align="center" id="submitLink">@Html.ActionLink("Next", "address", "PES", new { abc= "xyz" }, null)</div>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $("#submitLink").click(function () { $("#form").submit(); });
});
```

Form is not submitting when i click next link
What i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your DOM ready first and as suggested by these guys "provide id to your a tag instead of div"

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#submitLink").click(function () { $("#form").submit(); });
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the ID on the link instead of the div:

```
<div align="center">

    @Html.ActionLink("Next", "address", "PES", new { abc= "xyz" },  new { id="submitLink" })

</div>
```

You should also consider setting an action and if needed a controller to your form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionName","controller",FormMethod.Post, new { id="form"}))
{

}
```

The overload of your BeginForm you're using now is that you set routeValues to id="form".

Comment: I tried it also but still no output. One thing more i want to share is that when i click this link and updated my script to alert user onclick event of link of link then it works for me quite well.

Comment: Do you know about a tool called firebug? Can you use it to see if there acctually are a request sent to the server? http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use this script instead of your script and check it now it works or not...
please provide submitLink id to anchor tag....

```
$.document.ready(function () {
    $("#submitLink").attr("onclick", "$('#form').submit();");
    $("#submitLink").attr("href","javascript:void(0);");
});
```

I think this concept will works.....